# How do i customize Tier Price text?

Tags: magento-1.7

How do i change this text and colour it?

> "Buy 20 for £13.90 each and save 14%"

I've changed its place from "/catalog/products/view.phtml" but the text is not able to change from this file...

Thanks.

Comment: After changing the place, have you cleared cache?

Comment: Altafhussain, it's not about cache, i changed its place and its working, but now, i'm trying to change the text. like "Buy 20 pieces or more for ......"
Thanks

Comment: If caches are enabled, and if you change anything in template files, css files etc, it will not take effect until you clear it. Disable CSS merging, and then edit the color of text. For text, enable template path hints and you will see that the text is coming from which template file. Then edit in that template file. Also you can edit this text in inline translation, enable it for english store view and edit it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tier price text comes from the template `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml` or from `/app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/bundle/catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml` for bundle products.

copy the files in your theme and change the texts.

Comment: There are lots of "Buy %1$s for %2$s' ........." text in tierprices.phtml file, which one i need to change?

Comment: @EmreNazlı, to be on the safe side, change all of them. Each one is shown depending on different tax settings and depending on how the prices are displayed. With tax, without it or both.